# SQL logic to select records

Tags: sql

I looking for a SQL to select records on below basis:

Order Table:

```
order  total item
1          2
2          1     
3          2
```

order detail table:

```
Order Item (QTY = 1 for all)
1      A
1      B
2      A
3      A
3      B
3      C
```

Inventory table :

```
Item QTY
A     1
B     1
C     1
```

If any order does not fulfill the QTY my SQL should remove that order.

please suggest how can I write this SQL.

Comment: please show the expected output and tag the database engine you are using

Comment: This is a good place to start: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the part you are having trouble with? DO you expect someone else to come up with a solution for you?

Comment: the expected result should be : orders = 2 is selected as order 1 and 3 cannot fulfill the QTY

Comment: looks like homework to me, as this is both generic and also something you would never do irl (you don't just delete orders)

Comment: pls edit your question instead of answering in comments  @Agnostic

Comment: Lazy student's homework?

Comment: i think i should use:  having  sum of each item on order  <= inventory  for that item, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you try to write a check for every purchase, or something. So, you want a script that checks whether there are enough items to make make the purchase (one row). Something like beneath does the trick (PS: this is t-sql dialect, I'm not sure what left outer join is in your language because your dialect is not stated).

```
select a.[order], a.item, b.Qty, b.Qty-1 as Qty_After_Purchase
from Order_Detail as a
left outer join Inventory_Table as b
on a.item=b.item
where (b.Qty-1)<0
```

And then make sure the purchase is not executed, or the request is rolled back, or put on the waiting list, or something. Beware, this is per one row. If you need something else, than state that in your question.

Now, I'm not 100% sure this is what you want...

PS: in t-sql you have to place 'order' between '[' and ']', because elwise the dbms sees it as a specific command.

Comment: i'm pretty sure this sql does not work since there is no `on` clause in your `join `

Comment: oh, hehe, good one @A ツ. Origin of every screw up: no testing before delivering... :) I'll change it in a moment with the ON statement to it.

Comment: b.Qty-a.item as Qty_After_Purchase ; here a.item do you mean a.QTY ?? because a.item is char.

Comment: ehm. yes. I changed it to '-1', because that is what actually the quantity per row is there.